# How can one create a continuous function that transitions a 2d input through a range of possible functions

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, functions

This is my first question here, hopefully it isn't too bad. Apologies in advance if it isn't formulated in a manner coherent with the expected formalism. Let me know if I need to make corrections and I will do so immediately.

I am trying to create a 3D function for which the first 2 (x;y) are parameters are contiguous of a 2D space. i.e. [example 2d function graphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKuVg.jpg)

and the third (z) acts to transition/"morph" the function that is applied to the prior 2 rational numbers through the possible relations between x and y.
A discrete (naive) implementation of this might be merely to instantiate a case statement

```
X(x;y;z) = { 
          |y|, for z=1 // absolute
          y^2, for z=2 // quadratic
          y^3, for z=3 // cubic
          ...
          x*y  for z=n
          }
```

Are there any methods by which one might transition the expression of the relation between x and y values with respect to a space parameterized by z. e.g

```
(identity(x;y) -> absolute(x;y) -> quadratic(x;y) -> cubic(x;y) .... // positive function (0<z)
-identity(x;y) <- -absolute(x;y) <- -quadratic(x;y) <- -cubic(x;y)) // negative functions (0>z)
```

Edit: z could also be a function parameterized by some value.

How might one implement something like this? Is there anything similar to this?
Best regards and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, we have a function of two variables, $x,y$, for each integer call it $f_n$. We want to find some continuous function of $x$, $y$, and $z$, call it $g$, so that for any integer $n$, $g(x,y, n) = f_n(x,y)$. In other words, When we restrict $g$ to an integer $z$ value it is the function we started with.

If continuity is the only requirement, we can interpolate using straight lines. The thought process is as follows. Suppose we wanted to find $g(1,2,3.5)$. Well, we know what $g(x,y,3)$ is and $g(x,y,4)$, so why don't we say that $g(x,y,3.5)$ is exactly halfway between $g(x,y,3)$ is and $g(x,y,4)$? You can write an actual formula for this. Here, $\lfloor z \rfloor$ will denote the floor of $z$, and define $R(z) = z - \lfloor z \rfloor$. Then our function $g$ is defined as $g(x,y,z) = R(z)g(x,y,\lfloor z \rfloor) + (1-R(z))g(x,y,\lfloor z \rfloor + 1)$.

You should note that while this will be continuous, it won't be smooth or have other nice properties. I'm sure that there are ways to get those properties, but that would probably require some more complicated way of defining $g$.

Comment: Hey @memerson, thanks for the answer. Will try it out ...